# Two-way binding with RxJava on Android

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java, two-way-binding

Recently I've been developing some functionality and it seems to me that it would be nicely modeled with some form of two-way binding.

Example: there's a screen where user can fill some forms and save some content. Later user can come back to that content and edit it. Content is stored in a DB so the content should be fetched asynchronously. I use RxJava and Mosby MVP to create MVVM-style connection between the fragment and presenter.

The problem is that forms should be validated on the fly, so any time some part of the View changes Presenter should be notified. But when asynchronous content from DB arrives (in case user is editing existing content) view can corrupt 'initial' state from DB because of the transition between the states. Also there's a risk of infinite event passing cycle between view and presenter (`distinctUnitChanged()` doesn't always help with this, because state can alter like 1-2-1-2-1)

I've found 2 workarounds but I am not satisfied with them because they're rather impure and don't feel like idiomatic FRP.

The first one is changing a view in the way that it doesn't send events until it received the first state from presenter.

The second one requires sacrificing Presenter purity. Presenting is setting a flag which tells if we should accept view's state change. It will skip events from view until it will receive the one it passed to the view (initial state).

Things are getting even harder because in Android view can disconnect and reconnect to the Presenter at any time (with or without saved state) and Presenter should be the source of truth.

If anyone has any examples of two-way binding implementation with RxJava or any ideas I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using  `swichMap()` (instead of `flatMap()`) when loading asynchronous content from DB as switchMap() unsubscribes from previous input validation while the user changes form.

Probably this solves your problem.

Btw. It seems that Mosby MVI module is better suited as traditional MVP for what you are trying to achieve (RxJava, Two-Way-Binding).

Comment: I use switchMap() but it doesn't solve my problem because my problem is that view state cannot be set at once and during that transition view state is incorrect. I would love to use something else but it is too late and the decisions wasn't mine to make.